# Javascript prototype across classes and files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a nodejs app, where i have defined classes in separate files. I have written a prototype for Array which i need to be accessed across all the classes how would i implement it, i tried defining the prototype in the main file of the project but i still cant use the prototype in all the classes.

for example

My prototype

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (e == this[i]) { return this.splice(i, 1); }
    }
};
```

My project structure

```
--main.js
--a.js
--b.js
```

i have my main.js where i require all other js

all the files use the prototype

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Add the whole prototype code, what you're trying to do with it in an example, along with any errors.

Comment: when all the classes are declared in the same file the code works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the other files are different modules then, it runs in its own JS context,  Best way is to create a module, which will add your `example` function to the `Array.prototype`  then from each module, call this function using `require`.

create a module file named extendModule.js and in that add

```
exports.extendModule = function(constructor) {
    constructor.prototype.example = function () {};
}
```

every other module which needs to extend Array.prototype

```
require("./extendModule").extendModule(Array)
```

Comment: thank you this worked, i just had to require this in the main file and it works across the project.

Comment: May I just add that it's a really, REALLY, _ReAlLY_ bad idea to mess around with the prototypes of ... well, basically anything you haven't created yourself.